# Using google spreadsheet as a database for a tumblr theme?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, tumblr

I am currently using tumblr as a website for my club. On tumblr there is a page, where every club member has a 'profile card' with their name, description and profile image.

I wondered if there is any way to create a google spreadsheet with the members' information and use the spreadsheet as a database, which can be accessed in the tumblr theme's HTML code.

I have been reading about Google App Scripts and JavaScript, but I just can't seem to connect those with tumblr and my idea (and actually I am not sure if tumblr is supporting it either).

So basically what I want to do in the tumblr HTML code is:
-Access a google spreadsheet
-Parse the data into a two-dimensional array
-Use array values to create new div elements

The reason, why I want to do this is because I don't want the members to login in tumblr and go through the hassle to mess with the code. They should be able to easily put their information into a spreadsheet, which is connected to the tumblr website, and every time the spreadsheet is changed, the website just needs to be refreshed and it is again up to date.

I will be thankful for any kind of help =)

Comment: Can you add custom Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site isn't a free coding service. Try to solve the issue yourself first, then post your code if you run into issues. Here's a good place to start: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script For more information about what kinds of questions are on-topic, and how to ask a good question, check out the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) docs.

Comment: @tehp Yes, that is possible.

Comment: @sean I wasn't asking for a code but rather for an answer to if it is even possible and what languages I need to take a deeper look into. I am a noob and I think there is no use going too deep into the matter if my plans are unfeasible.

Comment: Understood. @tehp's answer looks like a good start.

Answer (score 4):

I have done a similar task using Google Sheets as a database for small sets of data to be edited by non technical maintainers, and it can work quite well.

You have mentioned that you can add custom Javascript, so it should be possible in your case. Here are the general steps you would take:

- Setup your sheet to be accessed via API
- Pull data via the Javascript [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- Process and display the data on your tumblr site

This actually works quite well and allows for easy updating of what is essentially static data.

For more info on how you can open up your sheet and access it with the API check out [this article](https://www.blockspring.com/blog/google-spreadsheet-as-database) or ones like it available via Google.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out this way =D